# relative timestamp forward in Youtue (Webbrowser)

Tags: javascript, browser, youtube, browser-extension

Is there a way to jump to a certain timestamp while watching a video? I'm aware that I can do this with "?t=191". But that only works before I visit the site and it is absolute.

What I would like to do, is have a booklet or browser extension or something that allows me to jump to a certain relative timestamp. Say I'm at 1:10 and when I press the booklet I get forwarded 10 secs to 1:20. That should work directly on the youtube.com.

Comment: Just press the right/left arrow.

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks for the suggestion but I need to do this in JS. I guess I could just write a Script that does that by sending the keyboard left/right messages^^.  Haven't thought about that so, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Really don't get why anyone would want relative jumps? I mean you can have bookmarklet to go to specific time for an "important scene" but relative jumps what's the use?

Comment: @Viney We're thinking about having a youtubevideo as a game where you have to solve a crime that happens in "4D" ( 4th dim being time) and it would be great if we could implement the navigation to scenes with important cues via relative for/backwarding.

Comment: @HarrysKavan Is the video embedded in your own site, or is your intent to have the game playable directly on YouTube? If it's an embed, there's definitely an API you can use: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Comment: @ceejayouz yes we wan't to do both actually (on our site and directly on youtube). I'm aware of the api (thanky anyway). But my question is actually how to do that directly on YT (with browser extension, bookmarket or whatever).

Comment: I thought this was possible with normal YouTube video tools. I've definitely seen somewhat interactive videos where you can "make choices" by clicking and clicking actually jumps to a section. Here is the [Torment: Tides of Numenera interactive trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fjo1IyGCJVo) - it's one that does what I said. You get choices and get several different ends just by jumping around. It sounds like what you were describing in concept.